# Modifying XCTest log level for XCUITests?

Tags: swift, logging, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, fastlane

When I run my UI Test suite from XCode, the logs I get are quite useful and consist almost entirely of information about the elements I'm trying to interact with and the elements on the screen.

When I run my UI Test suite with the `keep-the-logs-around` options using Fastlane, the log looks mostly like this:

`13:52:03.660 xcodebuild[10946:917312] (LOG ARBITER) Rotating message buffer with 388 messages.
...
13:53:24.666 xcodebuild[10946:916508] (LOG ARBITER) Rotating message buffer with 825 messages.
13:53:26.514 xcodebuild[10946:917191] (LOG ARBITER) Dumping buffered message data; 21669 messages.`

and the bits of the log that are actually around look something like this:

`14:28:28.074 XCTRunner[10957:916546] <XCTWaiter: 0x608000011280> entering wait loop for 0.20s
14:28:28.166 XCTRunner[10957:926899] <XCTWaiter: 0x608000010470> watchdog first trigger, clearing _XCWaitLoopIsValid and waking other waiters
14:28:28.166 XCTRunner[10957:928326] <XCTWaiter: 0x608000010390> watchdog second trigger, weakWaiter: (null)
14:28:28.271 XCTRunner[10957:928326] <XCTWaiter: 0x6080000100d0> watchdog second trigger, weakWaiter: (null)
14:28:28.271 XCTRunner[10957:928386] <XCTWaiter: 0x60000001ee60> watchdog second trigger, weakWaiter: (null)`

along with having the actual useful information that would appear as described above when run through xcode.

Is there some way that I can reduce the logging level of the logs so that I don't get all of this noise?

Comment: Do you have Test and UITest both in your project?

Comment: I don't understand your question, Raksha.